# If two operators commute, then is it any basis of one of them also a basis of the other?

Tags: operators, angular-momentum, commutator

According to the [compatibility theorem](https://physics.stackexchange.com/posts/638642/edit), there exists a common eigenbasis for the eigenfunctions of two operators $\hat A$ and $\hat B$ representing the observables $A$ and $B$ if and only if they commute.

However, is *any* basis of $\hat A$ also a basis of $\hat B$, and *vice versa*?

Let's take for example the case of the $\hat L_z$ and $L^2_z$ operators. It is easy to see that the eigenfunctions $\Theta_m(\theta)$ of $\hat L_z$ are also eigenfunctions of $\hat L^2_z$.  Do these eigenfunctions account for the *complete* set of eigenfunctions of $\hat L^2_z$? They commute, but the compatibility theorem doesn't state that all the eigenfunctions of one operator are also eigenfunctions of the other. Would *any* basis of $\hat L_z$, say $\{\Theta_m(\theta)\}$, be also a basis of $\hat L^2_z$, and thus all the eigenfunctions of $\hat L_z$ also the eigenfunctions of $\hat L^2_z$ in this case?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/542852/2451 and links therein.